# offshoring work and tax dilemma

Tags: united-states, taxes, self-employment

My friend in USA who is a US citizen wants to hire her cousin from her native country and will be paying the relative as independent contractor.

Dilemma:

1. She does not have a registered business under her name. She's only
   working as a  freelancer and giving her relative the cut when she
   seeks help.
2. Does IRS like one payment method over other or they simply don't
       care as long as she can show the receipts?
3. It's only consulting work at the moment, so most of the
           communication is done over phone. Should they start engaging in
           written communication to keep records of the work done?
4. Is it okay to pay in one go to save money-transferring fees? Can she
       pay in advance?

Basically, she has not outsourced work in previous years, and she wants to avoid any red flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally for tax questions you should talk to a tax adviser. Don't consider anything I write here as a tax advice, and the answer was not intended or written to be used, and it cannot be used by any taxpayer, for the purpose of avoiding penalties that may be imposed on the taxpayer.

> Does IRS like one payment method over other or they simply don't care
>   as long as she can show the receipts?

They don't care as long as she withholds the taxes (30%, unless specific arrangements are made for otherwise). She should withhold 30% of the payment and send it to the IRS. The recipient should claim refund, if the actual tax liability is lower.

> It's only consulting work at the moment, so most of the communication
>   is done over phone. Should they start engaging in written
>   communication to keep records of the work done?

Yes, if she wants it to be a business expense.

> Is it okay to pay in one go to save money-transferring fees? Can she
>   pay in advance?

Again, she can do whatever she wants, but if she wants to account for it on her tax returns she should do it the same way she would pay any other vendor in her business. She cannot use different accounting methods for different vendors.

> Basically, she has not outsourced work in previous years, and she
>   wants to avoid any red flags.

Then she should start by calling on her tax adviser, and not an anonymous Internet forum.

Comment: The title contains *"offshoring work"* .. presumably "offshoring" means the worker is foreign / located outside of the U.S., and not likely a U.S. citizen (though we don't know for sure).  Withholdings not likely an issue?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea on the contrary - withholdings are very likely the issue. Transactions between US persons are taxed through the US persons' voluntary disclosure. Its the transactions with foreigners when the withholdings are required, because that's the only way for the IRS to tax foreigners on their US income.

Comment: Wouldn't a foreigner need to be somehow deemed a U.S resident in order to be liable for income tax?  Would it differ if it were two businesses as opposed to two individuals?  This just seems odd.  (Then again, I'm Canadian.)  If I contracted to an offshore development shop, I wouldn't need to withhold tax for them .. they would be taxable in their own jurisdiction.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea no. US taxes on all income sourced in the US. Non-residents pay only tax on that income to Uncle Sam (residents pay taxes on *worldwide* income, not only US-Sourced). It wouldn't make any difference if it was two businesses. If you contracted to an offshore development shop, you would indeed need to withhold tax for them, and they would have to claim refund from the IRS (including using treaty or foreign tax credit adjustments).

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea to avoid/mitigate that, the foreign individual/entity must fill W8BEN form and give it to the payer, in which they will declare what should be withheld (if not the default 30%), and based on what legal authority (usually a tax treaty).

Comment: Ah, yes .. W8BEN.  That rings a bell!  So really in such a case the receiver ought to do that, than to have the payer withhold anything and have to go through the trouble to claim the refund later.

Comment: oh my, the amount is so small - even her entire annual income (including the business expenses) is not even 5 figures. I wonder if it's supposed to be more for big-businesses or at least individuals with some considerable amount. Maybe there's a cut-off? Hmm.

Comment: @TPR not really... But filing a claim for refund is not such a big deal (getting ITIN is more complicated then filing 1040NR itself...). She can just give the relative a gift, of course, but she wouldn't be able to deduct it as a business expense.